# Weird WP -Cli Error Connection Refused

Tags: database, sql, wp-cli

I have a rather of wp-cli problem.

I am using wp-cli to import a db from my test server into my staging server and even though the import is successfully and everything seems to be working correctly on the staging server following the import....

The **PROBLEM** is..

before / after every wp-cli command is executed I get  "Connection Refused"  messages:

for example:

```
Connection refused
Connection refused
Connection refused
0 rows affected using SQL (in 0.005s).
Checking: wp_yoast_seo_links.language
Connection refused
Connection refused
Connection refused
0 rows affected using SQL (in 0.004s).
Checking: wp_yoast_seo_links.region
Connection refused
Connection refused
Connection refused
Connection refused

Connection refused
Connection refused
Success: The cache was flushed.
Connection refused
Connection refused
```

**Attempt Solution**
I tried to to us `wp config create` to make a new `wp-config.php` file in case the previous one was corrupted... but no luck.. error messages still persist.

Any ideas?

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: @JacobPeattie   It doesn't matter.   The error messages appear when I run -any- wp-cli command from terminal....

Comment: Ok well this sounds like a support question then, not a development one.

Comment: @JacobPeattie  turns out wp-cli and w3-total-cache plugin, don't play nice with each with migrating sites...  development. problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this post...  the above issue was caused by the w3-total-cache plugin being migrated between Test and Staging servers.

To fix the issue, I deactivate and exclude w3-total-cache tables from the Test server's db export, then I do the upload and import to Staging server, which has its own "local" copy of w3-total-cache installed.

poof, not more weird "connection refused" errors.